How to import a module when creating a component in Angular 17 standalone mode?
I recently upgraded to Angular 17 and started using standalone mode. In Angular 16, there was an app.module.ts file where I would typically import and declare new components or modules.
However, in Angular 17 standalone mode, I noticed that app.module.ts is no longer a requirement. Now, when I create a new component, I’m not sure where to import the corresponding module.
For example:
Should I still have a central module file, or should I add imports in the standalone component itself?
How does this work for shared modules or features like routing?

Can someone guide me on how to manage imports and dependencies in this new standalone structure?
I tried creating a new standalone component using the Angular CLI with the --standalone flag. I expected it to automatically handle module imports or provide clear guidance on where to include shared dependencies like routing or services. However, I couldn't figure out the correct way to manage imports for shared modules or other dependencies, as there's no app.module.ts file in standalone mode.

you should check the documentation where an explanation is already provided components routing
